# I can't use Ctrl ] to jump to a tab in windows gvim

Tags: windows, vim

I've opened help (`:help`) but I can't navigate the tags (such as the bars example).

On gvim, the closest thing that works is pressing <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, then <kbd>]</kbd> (not at the same time) which shows a list of tags.

Double clicking the tag works fine, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> works fine.

I'm on Windows 7, and my vimrc file is only the line `set nocompatible`, but it didn't work with the original vimrc file either.

The keys themselves seem to be working fine on other programs e.g. Excel.

**edit:** Reinstalled and it still doesn't work.

**edit:** Decided to just use `nnoremap <C-Enter> <C-]>` which works. I can only think that `C-]` is being hijacked by something else.

Comment: Have you tried it without any vimrc? In other words, renaming your current _vimrc file to vimrc-old, or something.

Comment: Tried that just now, doesn't seem to have had any effect.

Comment: Do you mean jump to a tag in the title? Does an error message show up when you hit `<C-]>`?

Comment: @FDinoff in the :help file they have a bunch of tags, like ``|bars|`` and ``|usr_01.txt|``, and I can't go to them through the shortcut. Nothing shows up when I press ``<C-]>``, not even in the bottom right.